No provider for MatDialogRef using angular material 19
I'm using angular 19 and angular material 19. Now I'm doing as far as I know some basic dialog stuff
I'm, lets say rendering FooComponent, which does the following
openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open<string>(BarComponent, {});

    dialogRef.closed.subscribe(result => {
        console.log('The dialog was closed');
    });
}

This works ok, the BarComponent is rendered as a dialog. However, now I want to close the dialog from inside BarComponent, so I injected MatDialogRef. As soon as I do that I get the following error
NullInjectorError: No provider for MatDialogRef!

BarComponent:
@Component({
    imports: [CommonModule]
    ...
})
export class BarComponent {
      private dialogRef = inject(MatDialogRef)

      closeDialog() {
         this.dialogRef.close()
      }
}

I tried many things, such as import MatDialogModule in FooComponent and BarComponent, but none of them helped. Any suggestions what might be the issue here?

issue not reproducible, please replicate the issue and share back on the question stackblitz

can you import MatDialogModule in your module's import array

While creating the stackblitz I found the problem. I used Dialog instead of MatDialog
